# sfdx plugin installation crash: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dim' of undefined

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

Since today, my docker image crash because sfdx `plugins:install` seems to crash

I tried with 2 different plugins, and the result is the same

I also tried on Windows: same crash

```
$ sfdx plugins:install sfdx-essentials
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'dim' of undefined

$ sfdx plugins:install isvte-sfdx-plugin
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'dim' of undefined
```

Do someone has some workaround to "manually" install sfdx plugins (which are simple npm packages) without using `sfdx plugins:install` ?

*Note: My sfdx installation is `sfdx-cli/7.72.0 win32-x64 node-v12.11.1`*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can "manually" install plugins. The local commands are meant to be run in the project directory, e.g. ~/workspace/my-project.

For local npm installation, here's how that goes:

```
npm install sfdx-essentials
npm install isvte-sfdx-plugin
sfdx plugins:link node_modules/sfdx-essentals/
sfdx plugins:link node_modules/isvte-sfdx-plugin/
```

Or, once you've got your dependencies listed in package.json, the script can be:

```
npm install
sfdx plugins:link node_modules/sfdx-essentals/
sfdx plugins:link node_modules/isvte-sfdx-plugin/
```

Or, you can even clone the sources and work from there:

```
git clone https://github.com/...
sfdx plugins:link ...
```

There's at least a few different choices to work with.

---

For global installations, you can determine the spot you want to link to:

```
npm i sfdx-essentials -g
NPM_GLOBAL_DIR=`npm root -g`
sfdx plugins:link $NPM_GLOBAL_DIR/sfdx-essentials/
```

Comment: i which cwd folder can i run those commands ? any ? (i need to use them as global, so do you have a way to do the same with npm i sfdx-essentials -g ? )

Comment: @NicolasVuillamy Added global install option as well. For the non-global version, it's your project directory, e.g. ~/workspace/my-project

Comment: Solution tested in my Dockerfile -> installation ok -> use of plugins ok :) Let's hope SFDC will solve this bug soon , thanks a lot for your quick and efficient help :)

Comment: It works, thank you

Comment: This problem is already noticed by Salesforce and will be fixed this week: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/592

Comment: Thanks. I was getting this error with `sfdx-diff` and ran command `sfdx plugins:link node_modules/@salesforce/sfdx-diff` and it works now!

Comment: @sfdcfox if you install a sfdx plugin globally through npm, and if the plugin bin is set as sfdx in your package.json then it will override sfdx completely and sfdx force and sfdx plugins won't exist anymore.